# alter VLOOKUP Range based on another value

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

If a cell A1 displays an H, i'd like A3 to use a Vlookup.  If A1 is then changed to an F, i'd like A3 to use a different Vlookup table.  I'm unsure how to do this in Excel.

Comment: You could say     =if(a1="h", {vlookup 1}, {vlookup2}

Comment: As an aside, I would highly recommend that you learn to use INDEX/MATCH instead of VLOOKUP. It is a little more complicated at first but once you understand it, it is far more versatile and it is far faster (important when you have a lot of look ups in a workbook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
'using IF
=VLOOKUP(E4, IF(A1="F",tables!$A$7:$B$107, tables!$A$114:$B$214), 2, FALSE)
'using OFFSET
=VLOOKUP(E4, OFFSET(tables!$A$7, 107*(A1="H"), 0, 101, 2), 2, FALSE)
```

Comment: Saying too many arguments.  Because im trying to return column 2 in the lookup?

Comment: =VLOOKUP(E4, IF(E4="H", Tables!$A$114:$B$214,2,Tables!$A$7:$B$107,2), 1, FALSE)

Comment: @beginner2018jul - Should be `=VLOOKUP(E4,IF(A1="H", Tables!$A$114:$B$214,Tables!$A$7:$B$107), 2, FALSE)`